# Power Apps as replacement of InfoPath

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

We have decided to move away from InfoPath, since there is no investment. We are looking for some OOTB things like Power Apps for our SharePoint online platform. What issues might we come across while using Power Apps as a possible replacement of InfoPath?

Answer (score 2):

**InfoPath Scenarios not supported by PowerApps**

If you use InfoPath for any of the following scenarios, PowerApps is not recommended, even by Microsoft, as a replacement:

- Offline scenarios in which InfoPath Filler can be used without an Internet connection.
- Rich XML document scenarios in which forms can be moved, shared, reopened, edited, or processed for data.
- Wider audience scenarios in which users outside the organization are filling the forms. PowerApps only supports appropriately licensed users in the same organization.

Refer: [PowerApps Replacing InfoPath: 3 Things to Know](https://blog.formotus.com/powerapps/powerapps-replacing-infopath-successor)

Answer (score 0):

Is Infopath depreciated? Yes. Could PowerApps be an alternative to designing list forms, sounds good idea. But I have noticed in my tenant that the option visible below is still not available.

[image]

The only thing I am able to do is, create no-code forms using PowerApps. These  forms have their own Url and can be shared with users. But they aren't embedded within the lists. So it is better to wait for feature to be officially available.

Answer (score 0):

The main disadvantage is a design environment
while in Infopath design area is wider and tools pane spacing is not comparatively fair in Power Apps